# nginx config Location for pretty urls in laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx

I could't find info on internet.

I'm trying to create an admin area but leaving one webhook free of password (I use htpassword) but for some reason is not working, maybe it has to do with the laravel's pretty urls

This is working, being assets a real folder

```
location /assets/ {
    auth_basic          off;
    allow all;
}
```

This is not working:

```
location /index.php/webhook {
    auth_basic          off;
    allow all;
}
```

So I added this but is not working either:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

So I ended this with a slash, `location /index.php/webhook/` but still not.

For reference:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name xxx.com;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    root /home/www;
    #more configs like ssl#

    location / {
        limit_req   zone=login  burst=5  nodelay;
        limit_req_status 503;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

Any idea? :)

Answer (score -1):

I tried the embedded url credentials like this https://user:pass@xxx.com but the webhook wasn't compatible with this auth.

So I end up doing a workaround, I put allow to the webhook provider IP's so they automatically allowed without user/passw.

Easy right? It took me 2h to find this possibility out haha